# How to run ado file in another ado file in Stata?

Tags: stata

In R, I can run another R script using

```
source("script.R")
```

How can I do the same in Stata?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Stata, there are two types of scripts:

1. There are do-files, which are sequences of the commands as you type them, which may contain pretty much anything,
   and
2. There are ado-files, which are self-contained program scripts. Ado stands for "Automatically loaded DO files".

The primary distinction is that to execute the do-file, you need to `do` it or `run` it:

```
do whatever.do
```

shows the output, and

```
run whatever.do
```

suppresses the output.

The automatically loaded do-files, as the name implies, are loaded automatically. When you type

```
blah blah1 blah2
```

Stata will first look for the program `blah` in its memory. If it is not there, it will look for file `blah.ado` in the subdirectories identified in its `adopath` that by default includes Stata's own directories, as well as the current directory (type `adopath` to find out more, if you are interested). If it finds this `blah.ado`, it will (1) make sure it has `program define blah` inside it, and (2) try to execute this program with whatever arguments you supplied (`blah1 blah2`). If it fails to find the file `blah.ado` anywhere, it will issue an error message:

```
   . blah blah1 blah2
   unrecognized command:  blah
   r(199);
```

Comment: You can definately have more than one program defined in a .ado file. In this case, the top program can call later programs.  Many of .ado files you use are built this way. I'm not sure how Stata handles a pontial naming conflict with other programs in your adopath, but it would be easy to test.

Comment: Note that an ado file can run do-files

Answer (score 0):

Stata will search for the ado file in the default directories as the top answer indicated. To see your system default directories, type:

`. sysdir`

You can manually change the directory (e.g., the PERSONAL path) for ado files to the folder you like, using:

`. sysdir set PERSONAL "C:\your-ado-folder"`

Credit: https://kb.iu.edu/d/arur

Comment: This does not answer the question.